# embedding a matplotlib graph in a Tkinter canvas widget class

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, embed

I am trying to create a Tkinter widget class that embeds a matplotlib graph in a canvas object. The code I have written almost works but doesn't seem to exit properly when the widget is closed. Here is the code I am using. This is not the actual matplotlib graph code I am using but something I wrote for the purpose of asking this question. My original matplotlib graph code is very long and is too impractical to try and copy for this post.

```
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def schart2(stock_sym):
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    y = [20,21,20.5, 20.8]
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()

class StockChart(Frame):
    def __init__(self, stock_sym=''):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.makeWidgets(stock_sym)

    def makeWidgets(self, stock_sym):
        #self.f = graphData(stock_sym,12,26)
        self.f = schart2(stock_sym)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    StockChart('ACAD').mainloop()
```

When I run this code the widget is properly drawn and behaves as expected, but when I click the close icon button the widget disappears from the screen but the code continues to run and the idle prompt never reappears, instead the idle prompt just has a flashing cursor but no prompt. Normally when I create a widget like this, when I click the close icon button the widget closes and the underlying code also exits returning me to the normal idle prompt. If anyone has any ideas on how to get this code to exit properly I would appreciate the help. I am assuming that the problem is somehow related to the portion of the code which does the matplotlib embedding. Sincerely, George

Comment: Probably because you've replaced your actual graph code, this code doesn't run at all (notice your namespace problems and the fact that schart2 does not return a figure, among other things) - please fix it so people who want to help you debug actually can.

Comment: I appreciate your response but this code runs fine. When I run this exact code that I have posted everything works exactly as I have described. Sincerely, George

Comment: You get a figure but you also get: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'` from the `FigureCanvasAgg.__init__`. Because, as I said, schart2 does not return a figure. Pay attention to your error messages.

Comment: I appreciate your response. I am not getting any error messages when I run this code. When I run this code I get the graph figure with no error messages. When I quit the figure I get a blinking cursor in the idle window but no idle prompt and no error messages. If I run just schart2 by itself a figure is returned (the chart my code specifies is drawn) and when I close this graph figure the code finishes and I am returned to the expected idle prompt.

Comment: The error message you described occurs if the "matplotlib.use('TkAgg')" statement is not included in the import section of the code. It is my understanding the the "self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f)" section of the code will not function if the "matplotlib.use('TkAgg')" statement is not included. Sincerely, George

Comment: If you don't get an error message, there just must be something different about how your IDE handles stderr - do you get them if you run it from a vanilla python terminal?  The figure you're getting is purely from matplotlib alone, from the plt.plot() and plt.show() (which is why you get it from running schart2 alone).  As written you're not getting anything from Tkinter at all...

Answer (score 1):

You're not accessing Tkinter at all using this code, because your function schart2 returns `None`, which is then assigned to `self.f` and used for `self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f)`.

Rather, the window you're getting is from Matplotlib - the `plt.plot` and `plt.show` commands pop up a pure matplotlib figure.

To get an embedded figure in Tkinter the way you want, all you have to do is re-do schart2 to return a figure, and don't use pyplot:

```
def schart2(stock_sym):
    x = [1,2,3,4]
    y = [20,21,20.5, 20.8]
    fig = Figure()
    axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
    axes.plot(x,y)
    return fig
```

**In addition:**

You'll also want to remove the `self.canvas.show()`, because it causes a Tkinter error about an 'update_idletasks' attribute, but I'm not enough of a Tkinter expert to figure that one out, plus it's a separate question (there are already a few discussions on SO).  There is also a namespace issue - take the `Tk.` off of `side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH`, because you've done `from Tkinter import *`.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your response. I made all the changes you suggested and it eliminated the problem of the matplotlib graph not closing correctly however it does bring up another error message. Here is the error message I am receiving: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_idletasks'

Comment: My biggest issue is that the primary fix was to the graph code and not to the Tkinter code and because the graph code I used in this post was  simplified graph code and not my actual graph code I will have to figure out how to make the necessary adjustments to my actual graph code. Thanks again for your help. Sincerely, George

Comment: Well, that was what was causing the behavior you described. The other error is something unrelated. Try looking at the various questions on SO on that topic to see if they answer that question.